# Twitter Bootstrap and Font-Awesome: Some fonts appear as double (and more)

Tags: fonts, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Specifically...

```
<i class="icon-ok"></i> and <i class="icon-hand-up"></i>
```

...appear as double or quadruple.

[image: This is what I am seeing]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Customize Twitter Bootstrap [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). Make sure to uncheck the default "Icons" under "Base CSS."

Because you haven't done this, both Glyphicons and Font Awesome icons are visible.

Comment: Thanks. StackOverflow really needs to invest in a "tip" button.